# Printing out API result with ngFor Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api, ngfor

I'm trying to print json response in my web panel. When I try to display full response it works perfectly but then I try to use ngFor i get those errors in form the browser:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
```

this is a method that I try to use:

```
 <div *ngFor="let subject of lstresult.result.subject | json " class=" col-lg-4">
  <div class=" card card-chart">
    <div class=" card-header">
      <h5 class=" card-category">Completed Tasks</h5>
      <span>{{ subject | json }}</span>
      <br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class=" card-body">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

class prepaired for API looks like this:

```
   export interface VatAPI {
      result: EntityResponse;
    }
    
    export interface EntityResponse {
      subject: Entity[];
      requestDateTime: string;
      requestId: string;
    }
    
    export interface Entity {
      authorizedClerks: EntityPerson[];
      regon: string;
      workingAddress: string;
      hasVirtualAccounts: boolean;
      statusVat: string;
      krs: string;
      restorationBasis: string;
      accountNumbers: string[];
      registrationDenialBasis: string;
      representatives: EntityPerson[];
      residenceAddress: string;
      registrationDenialDate: Date;
      restorationDate: Date;
      name: string;
      registrationLegalDate: Date;
      removalBasis: string;
      removalDate: Date;
      nip: string;
      partners: EntityPerson[];
      pesel: string;
    }
    
    export interface EntityPerson {
      firstName: string;
      lastName: string;
      nip: string;
      companyName: string;
    }
```

and API request looks like this:

```
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) {}
  getcomments(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpclient.get(
      "https://wl-api.mf.gov.pl/api/search/nips/5213003700,6151001756?date=2020-07-27"
    );
  }
}
```

for some context full example response look like this:

```
"result" : { "subjects": [ { "name": "ARTUR PIKOR, EWA PIKOR SKLEP \"MERCEDES\" AUTO SERWIS S.C.", "nip": "6151001756", "statusVat": "Czynny", "regon": "230180142", "pesel": null, "krs": null, "residenceAddress": null, "workingAddress": "LUBAŃSKA 5, 59-903 ZGORZELEC", "representatives": [], "authorizedClerks": [], "partners": [], "registrationLegalDate": "1994-12-29", "registrationDenialBasis": null, "registrationDenialDate": null, "restorationBasis": null, "restorationDate": null, "removalBasis": null, "removalDate": null, "accountNumbers": [ "75109019680000000106202838" ], "hasVirtualAccounts": false }, { "name": "FUNDACJA WIELKA ORKIESTRA ŚWIĄTECZNEJ POMOCY", "nip": "5213003700", "statusVat": "Zwolniony", "regon": "010168068", "pesel": null, "krs": "0000030897", "residenceAddress": null, "workingAddress": "DOMINIKAŃSKA 19C, 02-738 WARSZAWA", "representatives": [], "authorizedClerks": [], "partners": [], "registrationLegalDate": "2004-04-19", "registrationDenialBasis": null, "registrationDenialDate": null, "restorationBasis": null, "restorationDate": null, "removalBasis": null, "removalDate": null, "accountNumbers": [ "79114010100000524444001001", "14114010100000524444001007", "56114010100000524444001027", "29114010100000524444001028", "29124011121111001000177255" ], "hasVirtualAccounts": true } ], "requestDateTime": "08-08-2020 19:25:11", "requestId": "1khm1-88d50kn" }
```

component.ts code:

```
this.ApiService.getcomments().subscribe((data) => {
  this.lstresult = data;
});
```

perhaps it's a beginner mistake but I cannot solve this problem ;)

Comment: Why are you using the `json` pipe with an `ngFor`?

Comment: how do you fill `lstresult`? cna you add `.ts` code for it?

Comment: @micronyks I've added the code

Comment: can you try replacing json with async ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume **data** has shown **json response**. Then, you need to make following changes to HTML,

```
<div *ngFor="let subject of lstresult.result.subjects" class=" col-lg-4">
```

Comment: thanks for the help, your solution do aint work, but it made me think. i needed to use the following code <div *ngFor="let subject of lstresult.result.subjects" class=" col-lg-4"> and change name of the object in the class from "subject" to "subjects"

Comment: I don;t understand why do you put  `.result` in `lstresult.result.subjects`  ?

Comment: @micronyks I think he missed the result object, the response is {result: {subjects: [...]}}. Just hit the API in browser ;)

Comment: my bad, i miss pasted the json response there should "result" : at the front

Comment: @tymon.zarski don't expose your API or the complete response to the public forum. Just use some dummy values..

Comment: it's a national API accessible for everyone, btw that are test values ;)

Answer (score 0):

1_ Your response is already returned as json from the API. No need to `json` pipe

2_ngFor is trying to reach the data inside `lstresult` object but it cannot because the data is not yet loaded. So use `async` pipe instead of `json`.

Comment: i can fully agree with a first point, but now with the second coz no pipe is needed, that's for help tho

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use async pipe in your ngFor because your json results are observable so ngFor must wait for the results. A simpler way to handle this issue is to use a ngIf to check results in one level upper than ngFor.